# Install DHCP failover on domain controllers vs member servers?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, domain-controller, failover, best-practices

What is the recommendation for installing DHCP failover; domain controllers or member servers?

I can't seem to find any recommendations either way.  I did find an old question here pertaining to security suggesting DHCP should never be on a Domain Controller but that was for Sever 2003.

In this case I'm looking at Server 2012R2.  I can either add the DHCP role to two domain controllers or fire up two new virtual member servers on our Hyper-V cluster.

This is an Intranet with 7 existing domain controllers running 2008R2 with approximately 300 hosts using DHCP (servers are static IPs on a seperate subnet).  We will be adding 2 new DCs and a new Hyper-V cluster.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're asking. Are you asking how to configure HA for DHCP or are you asking whether or not DHCP should be installed on a DC?

Comment: Thanks.  I've modified the question to be more clear.  Is it recommended to install DHCP on the DC or on separate member servers.

Comment: The only best practice info I can find relating to DHCP on a DC is from the BPA as related in this article - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941181(WS.10).aspx. In my experience I see it installed most often on DC's, even in large scale multi-national companies.

Answer (score 1):

As Murisonic comments, there is no definitive answer to this, all I can say is that the DHCP role is supported on a DC. On the plus side less VM's less overhead, possible slight performance because DNS and DHCP are on the same servers.  I can't really think of any downsides so I would go ahead.  Also have a look at the  IP address Management (IPAM) role for management and logging .. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj878343.aspx

Comment: IPAM is absolute overkill. I wouldn't recommend it to anyone with less than hundreds of devices, dozens of subnets and multiple branch offices.